# Should I consolidate session management using Sails.js and Stormpath?

Tags: node.js, session, express, sails.js, stormpath

I'm investigating using Stormpath for our user Management.

I currently have a Sails.js application which uses Node.js / Express.js. Currently, session management is handled by the default Sails.js framework, which relies heavily on Express' session middleware.

Sessions are stored in a shared Redis database on production so that we can keep our multiple API servers stateless.

My question is will the two session management systems conflict and/or cause bugs? Do they have to be consolidated or can we safely keep them separate? if they have to be combined, how do you configure the middleware?

As a note we won't be storing much user data on Stormpath, we'll only be using them as a auth/token provider.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'd love to see a sails.js <--> stormpath integration!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the author of the express-stormpath library, which is what I'm assuming you're evaluating.

You can indeed use your own sessions in addition to the stormpath ones. The way it works is like so:

Stormpath uses `req.session` to store a `stormpathSession` cookie. Any other cookies you create / store, will be handled by you completely.

It should work nicely with whatever session library you choose =)